# Entity framework does not detect an existing navigation property and attempts to re-add it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I define my model and relation similar to the [blob and post example on as on this page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

When I have an existing `blog` and want to add new `post`s to it, entity framework tries to add a new `blog` with each `post` addition. For instance:

```
var blog = new Blog(){ Name = "MyBlog" };
context.Blogs.add(blog);
context.SaveChanges();

// now I want to add a post to that blog
var post = new Post() { Name = "MyFirstPost", Blog = blog };
context.Posts.add(post);
context.SaveChanges();
```

At this point entity framework tries to *create a new `Blog` with `Name = "MyBlog"`* and does not recognize that I already have `blog`.

So when I look at the logs at `context.SaveChanges` I see the following:

```
INSERT INTO [Blogs] ([ID], [Name])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
```

And at this point, it raises an exception as the following:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Blogs' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Obviously it is trying to add a new `Blog` with an id such as `ID = 0`, which then fails because `ID` is auto-generated.

Hence, my question is why EntityFramework does not recognize the existing `Blog` and attempts to add a new one?

Comment: You should be adding the post to the existing Blog object instead of trying to insert it into the Posts collection directly.

Comment: can you elaborate? example?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: Herohtar means `blog.Posts.Add(new Post(){ Name = "x" })` or similar

Comment: indeed my point is what is the rational behind it? what you've posted works, and I am more interested in why my posted code causes creation of a new `Blog` entry.

Comment: @Hamed Your posted code also works. Except if the second snippet is run later on a *different* db context instance, i.e. in disconnected scenario. In which case `Add` will add all reachable untracked entity instances as new. See [Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) and related Saving Data documentation topics.

Comment: @IvanStoev could you provide an example? in fact in my app the two part run in separate context instances from a pool, but still I get the above-mentioned issues.

Answer (score 0):

Read the blog after saving (to set Id).

```
var blog = new Blog(){ Name = "MyBlog" };
context.Blogs.Add(blog);
context.SaveChanges();

blog = db.Blogs
   .OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
   .First();

var post = new Post() { Name = "MyFirstPost", Blog = blog };
context.Posts.Add(post);
context.SaveChanges();
```